# I installed the required packages but the gsap "TimelineLite" is not working/importing

Tags: javascript, npm-install

```
    import Highway from "@dogstudio/highway";
    import { TimelineLite } from "gsap";

    class Fade extends Highway.Transition {
        in({ from, to, done }) {
            const tl = new TimelineLite();
            tl.fromTo(to, 0.5, { left: '-100%', top: '50%' }, { left: '0%' })
                .fromTo(to, 0.5, { height: '2vh' },
                    {
                        height: "90vh", top: "10%", onComplete: function () {
                            from.remove();
                            done();
                        }
                    }
                )

                .fromTo(to.children[0], 2, { opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1 });
        }
        out({ from, done }) {
            done();
        }
    }
    export default Fade;
```

The timelinelite isn't importing for some reason. I tried re-installing but its simply not working.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import TweenLite, TweenMax, TimelineLite, TweenMax or the CSSPlugin anymore in the "new" v3 of GSAP.

All you need to do is to import gsap using their new syntax

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
import Highway from "@dogstudio/highway";
import { gsap } from "gsap";

class Fade extends Highway.Transition {
    in({ from, to, done }) {
        const tl = new gsap.timeline();
        tl.fromTo(to, 0.5, { left: '-100%', top: '50%' }, { left: '0%' })
            .fromTo(to, 0.5, { height: '2vh' },
                {
                    height: "90vh", top: "10%", onComplete: function () {
                        from.remove();
                        done();
                    }
                }
            )

            .fromTo(to.children[0], 2, { opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1 });
    }
    out({ from, done }) {
        done();
    }
}
export default Fade;
```

Comment: I tried but its still not working. And I am using scss but I don't think its an issue

Comment: Did you also change line 6 to this: const tl = new gsap.timeline();
And do you get any errors?

Comment: I did change but its still not doing its job and I didn't got any errors.